# Ionic popup with icons in buttons display problems

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

Here's the code:

```
    var importPopup = $ionicPopup.show({
        title: 'Select import source',
        subTitle: '(GPX, KML or WMS layer)',
        scope: $scope,
        cssClass: "popup-import",
        buttons: [
        {
            text: '<b>From Drive</b>',
            type: 'button icon-left icon-google-drive button-positive' 
        }, 
        {
            text: '<b>From URL</b>',
            type: 'button icon-left ion-link button-positive',
            onTap: function(e) {
                $scope.url();
            }
        },
        {   
            text: '<b>Cancel</b>',
            type: 'button icon-left ion-close-round button-assertive'
        }
        ]
    });
```

And the output it generates: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UE6W1.jpg

When only two buttons are displayed, the text and icons align correctly. When three buttons are displayed with only icons in the type, they align correctly as well. In the CSS the buttons are formatted into rows. Without this formatting the buttons look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8iHy.jpg

Here is the relevant section of the CSS:

```
.popup-import .popup-buttons
{
    display: block;
}
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: try to set width:90%;margin-left:10%;margin-right:10%;

Comment: didnt make a difference

Comment: if you can put it in jsfiddle to help you

Comment: Perhaps add the `html` markup of a single button? Our team of highly trained monkeys cannot inspect pictures. Yet.

Comment: how do you actually want the icon and button to display?

Comment: Andrei: The html markup for the button is actually in the "Type" parameter, see: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPopup/.

Comment: Will: I'd like the text to be centered and fill the window, the size/font seems to get warped when icons are added

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css:

```
.popup-buttons .button.icon-left:not(.button-small),
.popup-buttons .button.icon-right:not(.button-small) {
  // fix for intel-popup with icons
  line-height: 40px !important;
}
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue